# jquery general remove class

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

i have a select tag with several option value, if a value is selected, then i add a class to another div, here is my jquery:

```
$('#modello').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Classe B") {
        $('#header-image').removeClass('add').addClass("mod_b");
    } else if ($(this).val() == "Classe C Berlina") {
        $('#header-image').addClass("mod_cla");
    } else($(this).val() == "Classe C Coupe")('#header-image').addClass("mod_cla");
});
```

what i really want is  to add a general remove class, without giving a name, then add a class, is it possible?

Comment: @Pdslink, Sorry, I didn't get your problem? What do you mean by *add a class `remove` with out giving a name*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
 $('#header-image').removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-*` custom attribute on the `<option>` to store corresponding class name on the element itself. On changing the option, get the classname from the selected option and add it to the image.

HTML:

```
<select id="modello">
  <option value="Classe B" data-class="mod_b">Classe B</option>
  <option value="Classe C Berlina" data-class="mod_cla">Classe C Berlina</option>
  <option value="Classe C Coupe" data-class="mod_cla">Classe C Coupe</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#modello').change(function () {
    $('#header-image').removeClass().addClass($(this).children(':selected').data('class'));
});
```